# Use .NET MVC3 to create and then download document

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My program:

1. Collects information from my website. (Jquery)
2. Sends data to the server. (Ajax post)
3. Server assembles data into document. (See .NET code below)
4. Automatically Downloads document. (file dialog is ok or some other) (See .NET code below)

Jquery can easily perform step 1. However, if I use Jquery in step 1 then I feel locked into an ajax post for step 2. Meaning (as far as I can figure) step 3 and 4 need to be distinct controller actions. In this case, the document assembled in step 3 needs to be somehow transferred to step 4. I intend the document to be temporary so I'm not in favor of saving the data to a database. Furthermore, Session storage balks at complex datatypes like my model.

I put together code that appears to perform 1,2 and 3, however, there does not seem to be a way to easily transfer the data between 3 and 4. The document is temporary so I don't really want to store it in a database. I'd prefer temporary server side storage of some type.

So my questions:
1. Is there some other option besides an ajax post to get the large amount of text data (more than I would want for a get) to the server?
2. If there needs to be two controller methods (one to assemble document and another to download) how do I temporarily 'save' the data on the server? I'd prefer not to use a database and Session balks at my complex object..

Thanks,
Matt

DotNetCode assembles document:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FinalText(UserModel model)
{
    byte[] result = buildDocumentFromModel(model);
    return "success";
}
```

DotnetCode returns document:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult FinalText(int documentId)
{
    byte[] result = getDocument(i);
    return File(result, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("test.pdf"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with regular form submit.

Here are the steps:

1. Define regular form with inputs and submit button
2. Define ASP.NET action method that accepts **UserModel**, build the document and returns it as File result (instead of string "success").

Ajax is really not needed here, when the form is sent and the server respond with file for download the browser with automatically show save dialog without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page (no reload).

However if you want to achieve described behavior with ajax call and two ASP.NET actions (as you show in question) you can store the generated document in session as serialized string and deserialize it to byte array when needed.

I would recommend the first approach.